# Combining two Solr MLT query

Tags: solr, morelikethis, solr-query-syntax, mlt

Just wondering if it's possible to combine to separate MLT queries (based on filtering condition) into a single one. I'm trying to combine the results of this two query:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/mlt?q=title:"ABC"&fq=Source:("Test1")

http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/mlt?q=title:"ABC"&fq=Source:("Test2")
```

The Source field have different values for the two queries. I would like to combine the results of the two queries, is it possible to do it in a single query?

Any pointer will be appreciated.

Comment: you can build the query like http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/mlt?q=title:"ABC"&fq=Source:("Test1" OR "Test2")

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti .. Thanks, this is not I'm looking for. The problem here is that I'm looking for top 4 mlt results for bot source. There's a possibility that top 4 result might not contain any data from "Test2". Moreover, the first query can have more source like fq:=Source("Test1" OR "Test3" OR "Test4").